# How do I split sentences?

Tags: java, parsing, stanford-nlp

So, I found and am currently using Stanford Parser and it works GREAT for splitting sentences. Most of our sentences are from AP so it works very well for that task.

Here's the problems:

- it eats a LOT of memory (600M a lot)
- it really screws up the formatting of a body of text where I have to make a lot of edge cases for later on. (the document pre-processor API calls don't allow to specify ascii/utf8 quotes -- they immediately goto latex style, contractions get split into different words (obviously) and spurious spaces are put into different places)

To this end, I've already written multiple patches to compensate for what I really shouldn't be having to do.

Basically it's at the point where it is just as much of a hindrance to use as the problem of splitting sentences to begin with.

What are my other options? Any other NLP type of frameworks out there that might help out?

My original problem is just being able to detection sentence edges with a high degree of probability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to try sticking with the Stanford Tokenizer/Parser, look at the [documentation page for the tokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml).

If you just want to split sentences, you don't need to invoke the parser proper, and so you should be able to get away with a tiny amount of memory - a megabyte or two - by directly using DocumentPreprocessor.

While there is only limited customization of the tokenizer available, you *can* change the processing of quotes. You might want to try one of:

```
unicodeQuotes=false,latexQuotes=false,asciiQuotes=false
unicodeQuotes=true
```

The first will mean no quote mapping of any kind, the second would change single or doubled ascii quotes (if any) into left and right quotes according to the best of its ability.

And while the tokenizer splits words in various ways to match Penn Treebank conventions, you should be able to construct precisely the original text from the tokens returned (see the various other fields in the CoreLabel). Otherwise it's a bug.

Comment: thanks for pointing me in the right direction -- http://pastie.org/2602418 <-- this is what I eventually did in ruby (w/ a test suite for all my use cases) -- think I still want to get invertible=true on there somehow but haven't delved in yet to see how to get that going

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of sentence splitters available, performance will depend on your specific application.

It's very easy to get started with [Perl](http://search.cpan.org/~achimru/Lingua-Sentence-1.00/lib/Lingua/Sentence.pm) and [Python](http://medialab.di.unipi.it/wiki/Sentence_Splitter) versions. The Stanford Parser version I've found troublesome in the past; I ended up using a domain specific splitter (Genia). I also ran a regex based cleanup tool to look for badly split sentences and re-assemble them.

Comment: cool! thanks for the suggestions -- will be taking a look at these 3 options

Comment: come to think of it NLTK has to have sentence splitting in at least one form or another too.

Answer (score 1):

You have one way to split sentences from a text using the Stanford NLP and without having any character replaced by weird chars (such as for parentheses or apostrophes):

```
PTBTokenizer ptbt = new PTBTokenizer(
                    new StringReader(text), new CoreLabelTokenFactory(), "ptb3Escaping=false");
List<List<CoreLabel>> sents = (new WordToSentenceProcessor()).process(ptbt.tokenize());
Vector<String> sentences = new Vector<String>();
for (List<CoreLabel> sent : sents) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("");
    for (CoreLabel w : sent) sb.append(w + " ");
        sentences.add(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

The standard way of using DocumentPreprocessor will screw your original text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NLTK (especially, the [`nltk.tokenize`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html) package):

```
import nltk
sentence_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
text = "This is a test. Let's try this sentence boundary detector."
text_output = sentence_detector.tokenize(text)
print('text_output: {0}'.format(text_output))
```

Output:

```
text_output: ['This is a test.', "Let's try this sentence boundary detector."]
```